# Celery Flower: 'Monitor' graphs appearing in blank

Tags: celery, flower

I am using Celery and Flower. When I visit the 'Tasks' tab in Flower, I can see that my tasks are being registered and I can even see "Success" tag in the "State" column and everything.

However, on the "Monitor" tab, all the graphs ("Succeeded Tasks", "Failed Tasks", etc..) appear in blank.

Does anybody know why this might be?

Comment: add to the url the following get parameter ?https://flower.mydomain.com/monitor?updateInterval=15000